# Fill each blank with a digit 1-9 without any repetition

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Fill the following place holders with digits in the range from 1 to 9. Each digit only appears once and make the equation sum up to 100.

_ /_ * _ + _ * _ * _ / _ + _ * _ = 100

Also, what is the technical term for this puzzle?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Unfortunately, this *currently* looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere, and if this is the case, proper attribution is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a couple of solutions:

> ```
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 5 * 7 * 8 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 5 * 7 * 8 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 5 * 8 * 7 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 5 * 8 * 7 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 7 * 5 * 8 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 7 * 5 * 8 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 7 * 8 * 5 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 7 * 8 * 5 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 8 * 5 * 7 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 8 * 5 * 7 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 8 * 7 * 5 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  1 / 2 * 6 + 8 * 7 * 5 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 2 * 3 * 5 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 2 * 3 * 5 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 2 * 5 * 3 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 2 * 5 * 3 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 3 * 2 * 5 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 3 * 2 * 5 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 3 * 5 * 2 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 3 * 5 * 2 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 5 * 2 * 3 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 5 * 2 * 3 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 5 * 3 * 2 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  4 / 1 * 8 + 5 * 3 * 2 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 2 * 5 * 7 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 2 * 5 * 7 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 2 * 7 * 5 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 2 * 7 * 5 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 5 * 2 * 7 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 5 * 2 * 7 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 5 * 7 * 2 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 5 * 7 * 2 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 7 * 2 * 5 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 7 * 2 * 5 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 7 * 5 * 2 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  4 / 6 * 9 + 7 * 5 * 2 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 2 * 5 * 7 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 2 * 5 * 7 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 2 * 7 * 5 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 2 * 7 * 5 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 5 * 2 * 7 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 5 * 2 * 7 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 5 * 7 * 2 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 5 * 7 * 2 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 7 * 2 * 5 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 7 * 2 * 5 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 7 * 5 * 2 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  4 / 8 * 6 + 7 * 5 * 2 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 5 * 7 * 8 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 5 * 7 * 8 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 5 * 8 * 7 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 5 * 8 * 7 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 7 * 5 * 8 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 7 * 5 * 8 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 7 * 8 * 5 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 7 * 8 * 5 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 8 * 5 * 7 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 8 * 5 * 7 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 8 * 7 * 5 / 4 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 2 * 1 + 8 * 7 * 5 / 4 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 5 * 7 * 8 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 5 * 7 * 8 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 5 * 8 * 7 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 5 * 8 * 7 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 7 * 5 * 8 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 7 * 5 * 8 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 7 * 8 * 5 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 7 * 8 * 5 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 8 * 5 * 7 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 8 * 5 * 7 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 8 * 7 * 5 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  6 / 2 * 9 + 8 * 7 * 5 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 2 * 5 * 7 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 2 * 5 * 7 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 2 * 7 * 5 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 2 * 7 * 5 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 5 * 2 * 7 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 5 * 2 * 7 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 5 * 7 * 2 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 5 * 7 * 2 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 7 * 2 * 5 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 7 * 2 * 5 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 7 * 5 * 2 / 1 + 3 * 9
>  6 / 8 * 4 + 7 * 5 * 2 / 1 + 9 * 3
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 2 * 3 * 5 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 2 * 3 * 5 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 2 * 5 * 3 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 2 * 5 * 3 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 3 * 2 * 5 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 3 * 2 * 5 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 3 * 5 * 2 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 3 * 5 * 2 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 5 * 2 * 3 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 5 * 2 * 3 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 5 * 3 * 2 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  7 / 1 * 9 + 5 * 3 * 2 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 3 * 6 * 9 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 3 * 6 * 9 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 3 * 9 * 6 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 3 * 9 * 6 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 6 * 3 * 9 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 6 * 3 * 9 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 6 * 9 * 3 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 6 * 9 * 3 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 9 * 3 * 6 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 9 * 3 * 6 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 9 * 6 * 3 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  7 / 4 * 8 + 9 * 6 * 3 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 2 * 3 * 5 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 2 * 3 * 5 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 2 * 5 * 3 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 2 * 5 * 3 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 3 * 2 * 5 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 3 * 2 * 5 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 3 * 5 * 2 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 3 * 5 * 2 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 5 * 2 * 3 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 5 * 2 * 3 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 5 * 3 * 2 / 6 + 7 * 9
>  8 / 1 * 4 + 5 * 3 * 2 / 6 + 9 * 7
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 4 * 5 * 7 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 4 * 5 * 7 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 4 * 7 * 5 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 4 * 7 * 5 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 5 * 4 * 7 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 5 * 4 * 7 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 5 * 7 * 4 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 5 * 7 * 4 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 7 * 4 * 5 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 7 * 4 * 5 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 7 * 5 * 4 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  8 / 3 * 9 + 7 * 5 * 4 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 3 * 6 * 9 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 3 * 6 * 9 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 3 * 9 * 6 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 3 * 9 * 6 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 6 * 3 * 9 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 6 * 3 * 9 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 6 * 9 * 3 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 6 * 9 * 3 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 9 * 3 * 6 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 9 * 3 * 6 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 9 * 6 * 3 / 2 + 1 * 5
>  8 / 4 * 7 + 9 * 6 * 3 / 2 + 5 * 1
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 2 * 3 * 5 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 2 * 3 * 5 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 2 * 5 * 3 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 2 * 5 * 3 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 3 * 2 * 5 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 3 * 2 * 5 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 3 * 5 * 2 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 3 * 5 * 2 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 5 * 2 * 3 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 5 * 2 * 3 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 5 * 3 * 2 / 6 + 4 * 8
>  9 / 1 * 7 + 5 * 3 * 2 / 6 + 8 * 4
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 5 * 7 * 8 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 5 * 7 * 8 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 5 * 8 * 7 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 5 * 8 * 7 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 7 * 5 * 8 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 7 * 5 * 8 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 7 * 8 * 5 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 7 * 8 * 5 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 8 * 5 * 7 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 8 * 5 * 7 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 8 * 7 * 5 / 4 + 1 * 3
>  9 / 2 * 6 + 8 * 7 * 5 / 4 + 3 * 1
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 4 * 5 * 7 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 4 * 5 * 7 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 4 * 7 * 5 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 4 * 7 * 5 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 5 * 4 * 7 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 5 * 4 * 7 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 5 * 7 * 4 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 5 * 7 * 4 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 7 * 4 * 5 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 7 * 4 * 5 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 7 * 5 * 4 / 2 + 1 * 6
>  9 / 3 * 8 + 7 * 5 * 4 / 2 + 6 * 1
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 2 * 5 * 7 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 2 * 5 * 7 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 2 * 7 * 5 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 2 * 7 * 5 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 5 * 2 * 7 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 5 * 2 * 7 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 5 * 7 * 2 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 5 * 7 * 2 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 7 * 2 * 5 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 7 * 2 * 5 / 1 + 8 * 3
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 7 * 5 * 2 / 1 + 3 * 8
>  9 / 6 * 4 + 7 * 5 * 2 / 1 + 8 * 3
> ```

As for the technical term for this puzzle:

> I'm not sure.

Comment: If I may ask, what computer algorithm did you create? I found 1 solution with mine, so that's why I asked here

Comment: @Jeff A python script: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu1ft.png

Comment: Thank you, I will study this very carefully

Comment: You can just generate all permutations of nine digits and evaluate the expressions.

Comment: For the technical term, it's a [$ROT[13]$](https://rot13.com/)(sbezngvba bs ahzoref) puzzle.